# Program freezes while download a file in android

Tags: android, file, download, malformedurlexception

I am getting MalformedURLexception in the following code, and i have no idea, whats causing it.

```
public void down(String url)
    {     try {
        URL url1 = new URL(url);


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();   
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.ext");


        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //report progress


        }

        fileOutput.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
}
```

It says unknown protocol. 
The connection is totally fine unti the reading part comes up, 
before that the code is even printing right size of the file.
Also the file i am trying to download has a url like
http://download12.aomethin.com/blaa-blaa 
If i try to add www, the request starts redirecting.
Although i think this might be a noobish but I also want to know how to get the name of this file and save file with that name instead of the one i choose.

**Edit: the program is working now i just need to know how do i get the right name of the file. And make this a background process.**

Comment: @home Is that wrong     i am adding stacktrace right now...

Comment: @rigy73 where is your stacktrace?

Comment: @Alex Hey i tried again and the program is working now, the file is being downloaded but as that happens the app seems to hang. how do i change that.

Comment: @rigy73  Here's what I meant:  run DDMS, click on the "E" so you only see errors.  Then click ClearLog.  Next, run your program, when it crashes you should see some things pop up there.  Select all of them that pertain to your app and paste them here.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your help, but i can see that the program is working the file is being created, but i can't seem to get its right name, also the program hangs while its downloads.

Comment: @rigy73 I don't know what you mean by 'get its right name' but if it hangs you might want to do the download in a separate thread see this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: @Alex Thank for the link that is exactly what was happening with my app, As for file name it can be hello.rar or hello.mp3 on the server, i just need to know how to get that name from server and save the file with that name instead of somefile.ext.

Comment: We'd need to know more of the context to suggest good ways of getting that URL. Why does it have to be non-constant?

Answer (score 0):

downloading on the main thread is not a good practice; you should implement it on a new thread; because while downloading, the main thread is busy for downloading the file. If the waiting time be more than expected the system will generate "Not responding" error.

In order to do that you can use "[TaskAsync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)" or "[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/.../IntentService.htm)" or even making a new thread. though, I suggest [**TaskAsync**] as it is easy to implement.

here is a good practice to set the file name yourself:

```
public void downloadClicked() {
    InputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream f = null;      
    try {
        String path ="ftp://administrator:password@131.164.140.118:21/MyShedule.zip";
        String targetFileName = "MyShedule.zip";

        URL u = new URL(path);
        URLConnection c =  u.openConnection();         

        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
        String string = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString();

        in = c.getInputStream();

        f = new FileOutputStream(new File(string +"/kidsLibrary/"+ targetFileName));

        IOUtils.copy(in, f);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(KidsLibrary.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();            
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {         
            Toast.makeText(KidsLibrary.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {        
            Toast.makeText(KidsLibrary.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            Toast.makeText(KidsLibrary.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    } finally {
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(f);
        }   
}
```